# How to stop fusedLocationProviderClient inside the looper

Tags: android, kotlin, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-looper

I am slightly new to kotlin, so this may be a super easy fix. Basically, I followed a tutorial to get gps locations using the fusedLocationProviderClient and I am trying to stop the looper once it has found a location (i.e. I want it to find a location and then stop). I'm not very familiar with loopers, but how do I create a looper that works with the fusedLocationProviderClient that I can quit after I find a location.

Here is the code:

```
private fun setUpLocationListener() {
    checkSmsPermission(PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION)
    val fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    // for getting the current location update after every 2 seconds with high accuracy
    val locationRequest = LocationRequest().setInterval(2000).setFastestInterval(2000)
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)

    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        locationRequest,
        object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Location found")
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                for (location in locationResult.locations) {
                    Log.d(TAG, location.latitude.toString())
                    Log.d(TAG,location.longitude.toString())
                }
                if (locationResult.locations.size > 0){
                    // I want to quit here
                }
            }
        },
        Looper.myLooper()!!
    )
}
```

Mostly I think I need a bit of help on how to use loopers with fusedLocationProviderClient to create a looper that I can quit from inside.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could `removeLocationUpdates` from `fusedClient` to stop receiving updates

```
override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Location found")
     super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
     for (location in locationResult.locations) {
          Log.d(TAG, location.latitude.toString())
          Log.d(TAG,location.longitude.toString())
     }
     if (locationResult.locations.size > 0){
          fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(this)
     }
}
```

Comment: I found a different way. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have had the same questions as me, here's what I did:
for the location request variable, I just removed the ".setInterval(2000).setFastestInterval(2000)". Obviously, with these enabled, the GPS location always was going to get refound.